# Functions registered with ExternalInterface.addCallback not available in Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, swfobject, externalinterface

I'm working on a Flash game that needs to call some Javascript on the page and get data back from it. Calling Javascript from Flash works. Calling the Flash functions from Javascript (often) doesn't.

I'm using the [Gaia framework](http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/).

What happens:

1. The swf is loaded in with SWFObject
2. There's a button in the Flash file. On click, it uses `ExternalInterface.call()` to call a Javascript function. **This works.**
3. The Javascript function calls a Flash function that was exposed with `ExternalInterface.addCallback()`.
4. **Sometimes**, the Javascript produces the following error: `TypeError: myFlash.testCallback is not a function`.
5. When the error happens, it affects **all** functions registered with `addCallback()`. Gaia and some of its included libraries use `addCallback()`, and calling those functions from Javascript also produces the TypeError.
6. Waiting a long time before pressing the button in Flash doesn't solve the error.
7. Having Flash re-try `addCallback()` periodically doesn't solve the error
8. When the error occurs, `ExternalInterface.available = true` and `ExternalInterface.objectID` contains the correct name for the Flash embed object.
9. When the error occurs, `document.getElementById('myflashcontent')` correctly returns the Flash embed object.

Edited to add:

- This issue shows up in Firefox 3.6, but not Chrome or IE8. I haven't tried older browsers.
- I'm running the Debug version of the Flash player.
- My calls to `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` are wrapped in a `try...catch` block. When the JS error occurs, the `catch` block **is not** triggered. It's a silent failure.
- The error occurs when testing on a webhost, with the swf loaded from the same server as the page it's on.
- I set `allowScriptAccess = always`.
- Setting `flash.system.Security.allowDomain("mydomain")` doesn't fix the error.

From my Page class:

```
public class MyPage extends AbstractPage
{
    // declarations of stage instances and class variables

    // other functions

    override public function transitionIn():void 
    {
        send_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, callJS);
        exposeCallbacks();

        super.transitionIn();
    }

    private function exposeCallbacks():void
    {
        trace("exposeCallbacks()");
        if (ExternalInterface.available) {
            trace("ExternalInterface.objectID: " + ExternalInterface.objectID);
            try {
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("testCallback", simpleTestCallback);
                trace("called ExternalInterface.addCallback");
            }
            catch (error:SecurityError) {
                trace("A SecurityError occurred: " + error.message + "\n");
            }
            catch (error:Error) {
                trace("An Error occurred: " + error.message + "\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            trace("exposeCallbacks() - ExternalInterface not available");
        }
    }

    private function simpleTestCallback(str:String):void
    {
        trace("simpleTestCallback(str=\"" + str + "\")");
    }

    private function callJS(e:Event):void
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available) {
            ExternalInterface.call("sendTest", "name", "url");
        }
        else {
            trace("callJS() - ExternalInterface not available");
        }
    }

}
```

My Javascript:

```
function sendTest(text, url) {
    var myFlash = document.getElementById("myflashcontent");

    var callbackStatus = "";
    callbackStatus += '\nmyFlash[testCallback]: ' + myFlash['testCallback'];
    //console.log(callbackStatus);

    var errors = false;
    try {
        myFlash.testCallback("test string");
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.toString());
        error = true;
    }

    if (!error) {
        alert("Success");
    }
}

var params = {
    quality: "high",
    scale: "noscale",
    wmode: "transparent",
    allowscriptaccess: "always",
    bgcolor: "#000000"
};
var flashVars = {
    siteXML: "xml/site.xml"
};
var attributes = {
    id: "myflashcontent",
    name: "myflashcontent"
};

// load the flash movie.
swfobject.embedSWF("http://myurl.com/main.swf?v2", "myflashcontent",
"728", "676", "10.0.0", serverRoot + "expressInstall.swf",
flashVars, params, attributes, function(returnObj) {
    console.log('Returned ' + returnObj.success);
    if (returnObj.success) { returnObj.ref.focus(); }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this error out? I'm getting the same thing, only I'm getting in only in IE, not FF or Chrome. So strange

Comment: The issue seems to be only with Firefox and Flash in debug mode (not in Chrome) (only on Linux?).

Answer (score 2):

Calls made to JS via ExternalInterface are wrapped within a `try { }` block and that causes subsequent JS errors to get suppressed.

A workaround for the same is to cause a function closure in JavaScript and execute the actual code after a timeout.

Example:

```
function myFnCalledByEI (arg1, arg2) {

    setTimeout(myActualFunction () {
       // You can use arg1 and arg2 here as well!
       // Errors raised within this function will not be
       // suppressed.
    }, 0);

};
```

Comment: I can call JS via ExternalInterface fine. It's the other direction that's giving me problems.

Comment: I guess then, I am unable to provide any inputs on this as of now. If I come across something while your question is still unanswered, I will then surely post my thoughts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here was our scenario once we narrowed down all the conditions:

- Only on FireFox/Windows
- Only when wmode=transparent
- Only when using the js alert() function

In this specific scenario, ExternalInterface.call() would not fire right away. It only worked after creating a tiny delay with Timer class.

If we made wmode=window, or removed the alert() - everything worked.  Try using console.log() to display debug text in firebug.

The other gotcha? Whether your js function returns an array or object vs a string. Surprisingly returning the native js array was interpreted by an array in Flash.  Try outputting info about your return data like this:

```
var myRetVal = flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("my_js_func");
debug_txt.text = flash.utils.describeType(myRetVal).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be similar to the issue you are experiencing.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/translator-toolkit-api/thread?tid=58cda1b34ae1e944&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can see that type of error message if something wrong happened in Flash while making the call. Something like an uncaught exception.

Are you running the debug version of the player? That might give you more information about what's going on.

Also, is this consistent across browsers? I've seen old versions of IE having trouble accepting several consecutive Flash <-> JS calls.

J

Comment: If you look at my code, you'll see the addCallback() calls are wrapped in a try..catch block. The catch block never triggers. I'm encountering the error in Firefox 3.6, so it's not an IE6/7 issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tryied your code, and It worked ok if I place an alert before everything, so, I thinkg it is something related to some kind of time you have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in JavaScript?

```
if (myFlash)    
{
  if (!myFlash.testCallback)
  {
    if (__flash__addCallback)
    { 
       __flash__addCallback( myFlash, "testCallback" );
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Error: Flash External Interface injected JavaScript function not found. The external interface function won't work.");
    }
  }
}

myFlash.testCallback("test string");
```

I had used this in many cases.

Again at certain places I had to redefine __flash_addCallback and _*flash*_removeCallback functions to minimize the errors.

Presently I do not remember what I did for __flash_addCallback, but this is what I did for the latter:

```
if (__flash__removeCallback) 
{
   __flash__removeCallback = function (instance, name) {if(instance && instance[name]) instance[name] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've run into the same problem, and only in Firefox.

Following the advice given by THM we were able to find a solution.

In our case, the swf being inserted was inside a div being animated into view with jQuery.slideDown(). This apparently causes it to sometimes reboot while being started. In some cases this led to the callback functions not being available.

Fixed by calling swfobject.embedSWF only after the slideDown effect had finished.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I had the same Flash file on the page multiple times.  Even though each one of them had a different id/name, they were all using the same callback.